# Why are the POST request and console.log commands not working properly in this javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, http-status-code-403

I am running a development django server, and I am trying to capture data on how long a user stays on a page.  I have loaded `jquery`, `js-cookie`, and two other javascript files ([TimeMe.js](https://github.com/jasonzissman/TimeMe.js/blob/master/timeme.js) and [IfVisible.js](https://github.com/serkanyersen/ifvisible.js/blob/master/src/ifvisible.js)).  There are no console errors regarding any javascript, but I do get a 403 error

The relevant code is below.  However, the only console log output that appears is the `"test a"` that is not inside a specific function.  Additionally, I get a 403 error with the POST request upon unloading the page, which is usually associated with CSRF token issues.  I still get this error even if I change the value being sent to a constant value.

The visit view itself sends back a 204 code when manually viewed with GET, but it's not working with the POST request.

I am guessing that `"test b"` and `"test c"` not appearing is due to the refreshing of the console when the page changes/refreshes, but they do not appear for the `document.onload` function, either.

```
<body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="{% static 'ifvisible.js/src/ifvisible.js' %}"></script>

<script src="{% static 'TimeMe/timeme.js' %}"></script>

<script src="{% static 'js-cookie/src/js.cookie.js' %}"></script>

<script> var csrftoken = Cookies.get('csrftoken')</script>
<script> $.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr,settings){
    if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain){
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken",csrftoken);
    }
    }
});
</script>

<script>document.onload = function() {
console.log("loading timer");
TimeMe.setIdleDurationInSeconds(60);
TimeMe.setCurrentPageName("ARTICLE - {{object.title}}");
TimeMe.initialize();  
console.log("loaded timer");
}
</script>

<script> console.log("test a");</script>
<script>
window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
console.log("test b")
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("POST","/blog/handle_visit/",false);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
var timeSpentOnPage = TimeMe.getTimeOnCurrentPageInSeconds();
console.log("test c");
xmlhttp.send(timeSpentOnPage);
};
</script>
</body>
```

The view function:

```
@csrf_protect
def visit_unload(request):
    print "HI"
    print request.POST
    response = HttpResponse()
    response.status_code = 204
    return response
```

Edit: So, I fixed the code and used more of jquery's features, which seemed to do the trick.  Some of the code I used may have been outdated.

```
<script> 
var csrftoken = Cookies.get('csrftoken')
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr,settings){
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken",csrftoken);
    }
});
$(document).ready( function() {
console.log("loading timer");
TimeMe.setIdleDurationInSeconds(60);
TimeMe.setCurrentPageName("ARTICLE - {{object.title}}");
TimeMe.initialize();  
console.log("loaded timer");
});

window.onbeforeunload = function(event){
var timeSpentOnPage = TimeMe.getTimeOnCurrentPageInSeconds();
$.ajax({url:"/blog/handle_visit/",type:"POST",
data:{time:timeSpentOnPage},
});
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you have all those little `<script>` blocks? You've got jQuery, and you're calling `$.ajaxSetup()`, but you're doing the XHR with the low level APIs. That doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Yeah why are you not using jQuery for the AJAX? Is there a reason for the hand-coded XMLHttpRequests()?

Comment: And, to address the actual question, what exactly do you think you are sending in the POST? What are expecting to see in `request.POST`?

Comment: I am hoping to see the total amount of time a user has spent active on a page ("active" as defined in `TimeMe.js`)

Comment: I looked into shortening the code using jQuery, and it seemed to do the trick.  Now I am getting the proper post data on the server.